# Is it possible to include a module during initialize?

Tags: ruby, metaprogramming

Suppose one has the following pattern:

- Foobar class, which makes use of the logic in either Foo or Bar, but not both, depending upon the arguments given by the constructor
- Foo module, containing some logic
- Bar module, containing some alternate logic

A good example is an orbital elements calculator, which might take radius and velocity vectors, and compute orbital elements --- or alternatively, might take orbital elements and compute radius and velocity vectors.

Why not do this in a more straightforward way? Well, I want to make use of instance variables to allow just-in-time computations, e.g.,

```
def derived_value
  @derived_value ||= begin
    # compute only when/if necessary
  end
end
```

I tried doing this roughly as follows:

```
class Orbit
  def initialize options = {}
    if [:radius,:velocity].all? { |key| options.has_key?(key) }
      # Provide instance methods which derive orbital elements from radius, velocity
      self.include Orbit::FromRadiusAndVelocity
    else
      # Provide instance methods which derive radius and velocity from orbital elements
      self.include Orbit::FromOrbitalElements
    end
    initialize_helper options
  end
end

module Orbit::FromOrbitalElements
  module ClassMethods
    class << self
      def initialize_helper options
        @argument_of_perigee = options[:argument_of_perigee]
        puts "From orbital elements"
      end

      attr_reader :argument_of_perigee
    end
  end

  def self.included(base)
    base.extend Orbit::FromOrbitalElements::ClassMethods
  end

  def self.radius
    # Instance method to calculate the radius from the orbital elements
    @radius ||= begin
      # If radius is not already defined, calculate it from some intermediate
      # values, which themselves depend upon orbital elements.
    end
  end
end

module Orbit::FromRadiusAndVelocity
  module ClassMethods
    class << self
      def initialize_helper options
        @radius = options[:radius]
        @velocity = options[:velocity]
        puts "From radius and velocity"
      end

      attr_reader :radius, :velocity
    end
  end

  def self.included(base)
    base.extend Orbit::FromRadiusAndVelocity::ClassMethods
  end

  def self.argument_of_perigee
    # Instance method to calculate an orbital element
    # (There would be more instance methods like this)
    @argument_of_perigee ||= begin
      # If argument_of_perigee is not already defined, calculate it from some intermediate
      # values, which themselves depend upon radius and velocity.
    end
  end
end
```

Is there a better pattern / is this an advisable usage? Is it possible to do this?

Comment: It is not clear what you want to do.

Comment: You can't include module into an object, only instances of `Module` defines this method. You can however extend objects, but not with the modules you have written. Please update your question with clear description on what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: Is it clearer now? I'm not quite sure what I haven't explained well enough, but am happy to try to clean up parts that are confusing — if you can point them out to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can by including the module of choice in the singleton class (sometimes called eigenclass), not the object itself. So the initializer can look like this

```
class Orbit
  def initialize options = {}
    if [:radius,:velocity].all? { |key| options.has_key?(key) }
      self.singleton_class.include Orbit::FromRadiusAndVelocity
    else
      self.singleton_class.include Orbit::FromOrbitalElements
    end

    initialize_helper options
  end
end
```

If you're going to use this approach, then you need to adjust your modules accordingly:

1. No need for `ClassMethod` modules, all the method included are (supposedly) called from an object, not from a class
2. Remove the `self.` from the method names (except `self.included` of course)

The rest of the code can look like this

```
module Orbit::FromOrbitalElements
  def initialize_helper options
    @argument_of_perigee = options[:argument_of_perigee]
    puts "From orbital elements"
  end

  def self.included(base)
    base.instance_eval do
      attr_reader :argument_of_perigee
    end
  end

  def radius
    @radius ||= begin
    end
  end
end

module Orbit::FromRadiusAndVelocity
  def self.included(base)
    base.instance_eval do
      attr_reader :radius, :velocity
    end
  end

  def initialize_helper options
    @radius = options[:radius]
    @velocity = options[:velocity]
    puts "From radius and velocity"
  end

  def argument_of_perigee
    @argument_of_perigee ||= begin
    end
  end
end
```

That said, this solution is just for demonstration and I suggest you follow the example @Ollie mentioned in his answer as it is much cleaner.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not really sure why you want to mask an instance of two different entities under one but if you want simple decision logic based on arguments, this works:

```
# orbit.rb
module Orbit
  module_function

  def from_options(options = {})
    klass = if options[:radius] && options[:velocity]
              FromRadiusAndVelocity
            else
              FromOrbitalElements
            end

    klass.new(options)
  end
end

# orbit/from_orbital_elements.rb
module Orbit
  class FromOrbitalElements
    attr_reader :argument_of_perigee

    def initialize(options)
      @argument_of_perigee = options[:argument_of_perigee]

      puts 'From orbital elements'
    end

    def radius
      @radius ||= begin
                    # ...
                  end
    end
  end
end

# orbit/from_radius_and_velocity.rb
module Orbit
  class FromRadiusAndVelocity
    attr_reader :radius, :velocity

    def initialize(options)
      @radius   = options[:radius]
      @velocity = options[:velocity]

      puts 'From radius and velocity'
    end

    def argument_of_perigee
      @argument_of_perigee ||= begin
                                 # ...
                               end
    end
  end
end

# Usage
orbit = Orbit.from_options(radius: 5, velocity: 6)
orbit = Orbit.from_options(argument_of_perigee: 5)
```

If you want to do some kind of same-interface-thingy, may want to turn Orbit into a class and subclass it in the other classes but that isn't clear from your code.

Answer (score 1):

To me it sounds like a job for simple inheritance:

```
class FooBar
  def self.new(options)
    if [:radius,:velocity].all? { |key| options.has_key?(key) }
      Foo.new options
    else
      Bar.new options
    end
  end

  # common Foo and Barlogic here
end

class Foo < FooBar
end

class Bar < FooBar
end
```